# Android maps api key from server

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, api-key

Can I store my Google Map's API key on my server and fetch it from there and set it inside my app at runtime, instead of putting it in Android manifest file?

If not, why is it not supported?

Comment: Yes you can but that will make app slow, Sending request to server and receiving response. What's the use case ?

Comment: The API key is linked to your app's package and apk signature. Why would you need to fetch it from your server? What is your use case?

Comment: Well you know, the pricky PMs. They want everything customisable from back end!! @antonio: Can you point me to a tutorial / Maps SDK API where in I can set the same?

Comment: What if somehow a few of the keys get compromised and we want to replace the key with the new one? In that case, it'd be better to store the kyes into the backend right ?